# Why does Eclipse give "object sql is not a member of package org.apache.spark"?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing the below issue while working with a Spark SQL program through Eclipse.

Code line

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
```

gives:

> object sql is not a member of package org.apache.spark

**sbt file** details

```
name := "SparkXXSql"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.0" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.0.0" % "provided"

resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not a typo, then this is happening because your dependencies aren't actually resolving. When you add a %% then the scala version is automatically appended to the module, so you're really resolving spark-core_2.11_2.11 and spark-sql_2.11_2.11. Try removing the %% or the explicit _2.11 and reload your dependencies.